# Error: field type must be Input Type - cannot pass qlType into mutation

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql

I want to update a `person` with the `UpdatePerson` mutation. I don't want to specify each and every property in the `inputFields` - but rather want to pass the complete person object.

When I do that I get `Error: UpdatePersonInput.person field type must be Input Type but got: Person.`

Is there no way to pass complete objects rather than all of their properties to a mutation?

If there isn't, could you add one - because the amount of repetition of fields across a larger app with bigger objects can become very frustrating.

Same might be an issue on `getFatQuery` and `static fragments`. Repeating all the properties over and over again would be a nightmare.

Server:

```
/**
 * Create the GraphQL Mutation.
 */
export default mutationWithClientMutationId({
  // Mutation name.
  name: 'UpdatePerson',
  // Fields supplied by the client.
  inputFields: {
    person: {type: qlPerson} // <========================================
  },
  // Mutated fields returned from the server.
  outputFields: {
    person: {
      type: qlPerson,
      // Parameters are payload from mutateAndGetPayload followed by outputFields.
      resolve: (dbPerson, id, email) => {
        return dbPerson;
      }
    }
  },
  // Take the input fields, process the mutation and return the output fields.
  mutateAndGetPayload: ({qlPerson}, {rootValue}) => {
    // TODO: Process Authentication {"session":{"userId":1}}
    console.log(JSON.stringify(rootValue));
    // Convert the client id back to a database id.
    var localPersonId = fromGlobalId(qlPerson.id).id;
    // Find the person with the given id in the database.
    return db.person.findOne({where: {id: localPersonId}}).then((dbPerson)=> {
      // Mutate the person.
      dbPerson.email = qlPerson.email;
      // Save it back to the database.
      return dbPerson.save().then(()=> {
        // Return the mutated person as an output field.
        return dbPerson;
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Client:

```
/**
 * Create the GraphQL Mutation.
 */
class UpdatePersonMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation {updatePerson}`;
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {person: this.props.person};  // <========================================
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on UpdatePersonPayload {
        person {
          email,    // ??????????????????????????
        }
      }
    `;
  }

  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
      fieldIDs: {
        person: this.props.person.id
      }
    }];
  }

  static fragments = {
    person: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Person {
        id,
        email     // ???????????????????????????
      }
    `
  };

  getOptimisticResponse() {
    return {
      person: this.props.person
    };
  }
}

/**
 * Exports.
 */
export default UpdatePersonMutation;
```

Answer (score 9):

It's error because your `qlPerson` type was defined by using the `GraphQLObjectType` class, which is not an Input type. You must define it using the `GraphQLInputObjectType` instead. Basically, both of them take an object as an argument which requires same properties. So, you just need to use `GraphQLInputObjectType` instead of `GraphQLObjectType` as following:

```
export default new GraphQLInputObjectType({
   name: 'qlPerson',
   description: 'Dietary preferences',
   fields: () => ({
     firstName: {type: GraphQLString},
     ...
   })
 });
```