# Why doesn't GraphQL accept this scalar argument type, instead complaining "argument type must be Input Type but got: undefined"?

Tags: graphql

I have

```
export const getPicture = {
    type: GraphPicture,
    args: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
    },
    resolve(_, args) {
        return Picture.findByPrimary(args.id);
    }
};

export const getPictureList = {
    type: new GraphQLList(GraphPicture),
    resolve(_, __, session) {
        return Picture.findAll({where: {owner: session.userId}});
    }
};
```

and

```
const query = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Queries',
    fields: () => {
        return {
            getPictureList: getPictureList,
            getPicture: getPicture
        }
    }
});

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: query,
    mutation: mutation
});
```

Which throws:

> ```
> Error: Queries.getPicture(type:) argument type must be Input Type but got: undefined.
> ```

`getPictureList` works fine; `getPicture` fails  with a scalar argument type of `GraphQLInt` or `GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)`. I have tried making `getPicture` a `GraphQLLIst`, but it didn't help. I have tried making the argument `type` an Input Type, but it didn't help.

Why is the code generating the error, and how can it be fixed?

The stack trace is:

> ```
> Error: Queries.getPicture(type:) argument type must be Input Type but got: undefined.
>     at invariant (/home/jrootham/dev/trytheseon/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/invariant.js:19:11)
>     at /home/jrootham/dev/trytheseon/node_modules/graphql/type/definition.js:307:33
>     at Array.map (native)
>     at /home/jrootham/dev/trytheseon/node_modules/graphql/type/definition.js:304:52
>     at Array.forEach (native)
>     at defineFieldMap (/home/jrootham/dev/trytheseon/node_modules/graphql/type/definition.js:293:14)
>     at GraphQLObjectType.getFields (/home/jrootham/dev/trytheseon/node_modules/graphql/type/definition.js:250:46)
>     at /home/jrootham/dev/trytheseon/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:224:27
>     at typeMapReducer (/home/jrootham/dev/trytheseon/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:236:7)
>     at Array.reduce (native)
>     at new GraphQLSchema (/home/jrootham/dev/trytheseon/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:104:34)
>     at Object. (/home/jrootham/dev/trytheseon/server/graphQL.js:45:16)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:399:26)
>     at normalLoader (/usr/lib/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:160:5)
>     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/lib/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:173:7)
>     at Module.load (module.js:345:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:302:12)
>     at Module.require (module.js:355:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:13:17)
>     at Object. (/home/jrootham/dev/trytheseon/devServer.js:14:44)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:399:26)
>     at normalLoader (/usr/lib/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:160:5)
> ```

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but you only specified the type and seem to be missing the argument name (id).

Comment: @OP, parameterize `getPicture` in the root query. On a different note, you may consider naming `picture` instead of `getPicture`. It's more of a convention.

Comment: @AhmadFerdous queries passed into the schema definition do not need to be paramertized, they are passed parameters via the query call itself.

Comment: @BradDecker, thanks! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem isn't the return type of the query but the type you have specified to your args.

```
export const getPicture = {
    type: GraphPicture,
    args: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
    },
    resolve(_, args) {
        return Picture.findByPrimary(args.id);
    }
};
```

Assuming you meant to have an argument named "type" it should be:

```
export const getPicture = {
    type: GraphPicture,
    args: {
        type: {
             type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
        }
    },
    resolve(_, args) {
        return Picture.findByPrimary(args.id);
    }
};
```

here is an example from the graphql-js repo:

```
hero: {
  type: characterInterface,
  args: {
    episode: {
      description: 'If omitted, returns the hero of the whole saga. If ' +
                   'provided, returns the hero of that particular episode.',
      type: episodeEnum
    }
  },
  resolve: (root, { episode }) => getHero(episode),
},
```

See the full schema from the graphql-js repo here: [https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/**tests**/starWarsSchema.js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/__tests__/starWarsSchema.js)

Answer (score 26):

Just for reference, I got here searching the same error just not with `undefined`, but with my own `Product` type:

```
... argument * must be Input Type but got Product
```

Turned out that in GraphQL what you pass to a Mutation should be either scalar type (String, Integer, ...) or user defined **`input`** type, not `type` type.

http://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/

```
input ProductInput {
  id: ID
  name: String
}
```

I was trying to pass in my Product `type`:

```
type Product {
  id: ID
  name: String
}
```

This feels a bit redundant, but guess, I'll be glad for having it separated later.

Comment: To be even more specific, you need to define your input types as `new GraphQLObjectType`  from `graphql`,  like this answer explains: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35883106/4430640

Comment: I had this same problem and this helped me a lot. The link you have seems to be dead though, not sure what the right link is supposed to be.

Comment: @gkri Eventually yes. I am defining my schemas using _GraphQL schema language_ and passing it to Apollo's `makeExecutableSchema` More here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html